# How do I access Facebook 'likes' via API/text?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like users on my site to be able to say they are interested in something based on the facebook database.

For example, on my site a user would be able to search for 'running', it would access the Facebook API, and return the FB Graph API id for that interest.

Can't seem to find a way to do this in the Facebook documentation.  Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Example uses:  A user without a Facebook account (or not logged-in) would like to say they are interested in running. I would like to be able to query the FB database for that and return the ID for 'running' in the FB system.  Also applies if a user would like to identify an interest without adding it/liking it on their own Facebook profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fql and query the current user's interests. The below php code should do it once you have the userId that is currently logged in. Then simply search the resulting array to see if it contains "running" or equivalent keywords.

```
$fql = "SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid = [userId]";
$interests = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql
));
```

Comment: This does not address the goal that I am seeking.  I am not looking to identify a user's interests, but rather to allow a user to identify an interest outside of Facebook.

Example use case:  A user without a Facebook account would like to say they are interested in running.  I would like to be able to query the FB database for that and return the ID for 'running' in the FB system.

Comment: @user1318135 I don't think it is possible to return an interest without a user Id as they are a custom field

Comment: it should be possible, they are an absolute field per the Facebook graph, which can have relationships built to them.  See the coca-cola page listing here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Every 'like' is the liking of the respective page for that interest, so they are absolute and accessible... somehow ;)

Comment: @user1318135 Ok I think I see the confusion here! Firstly, the coca-cola example is a page. For example, if you wanted users that had an interest in drinks, then there is no way to return the coca-cola page based on the information in the graph. There are two ways to achieve what you want here. 1. You query the user table and check their interests against the interests field (as in the example above). 2. The other way to possibly do this is to query all pages that have the name 'running' in them (search?type=page&q=running) and loop through your friends to see which ones like these pages.